# Spring boot application Application startup failed

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-boot

I'm trying to learn Spring Boot on my own by reading online tutorials. I must have been done something silly and got the error. To reproduce the error, I must give the whole project. Here is the GitHub link: https://github.com/madsum/Springboot

Could somebody kindly let me knowe what is wrong?

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfigurationImportSelector.isEnabled(EnableAutoConfigurationImportSelector.java:42) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationImportSelector.selectImports(AutoConfigurationImportSelector.java:88) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImport(ConfigurationClassParser.java:388) ~[spring-context-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:207) ~[spring-context-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:165) ~[spring-context-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:140) ~[spring-context-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:284) ~[spring-context-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:225) ~[spring-context-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:630) ~[spring-context-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:461) ~[spring-context-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:737) [spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:370) [spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314) [spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1162) [spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1151) [spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at fi.ma.vegshopping.app.VegShoppingApplication.main(VegShoppingApplication.java:16) [classes/:na]

2017-04-13 10:20:35.199  INFO 10788 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@797badd3: startup date [Thu Apr 13 10:20:35 BST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-04-13 10:20:35.200  WARN 10788 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception thrown from ApplicationListener handling ContextClosedEvent

java.lang.IllegalStateException: ApplicationEventMulticaster not initialized - call 'refresh' before multicasting events via the context: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@797badd3: startup date [Thu Apr 13 10:20:35 BST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getApplicationEventMulticaster(AbstractApplicationContext.java:347) [spring-context-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:334) [spring-context-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1049) [spring-context-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1010) [spring-context-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleRunFailure(SpringApplication.java:794) [spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:325) [spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1162) [spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1151) [spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at fi.ma.vegshopping.app.VegShoppingApplication.main(VegShoppingApplication.java:16) [classes/:na]

2017-04-13 10:20:35.200  WARN 10788 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception thrown from LifecycleProcessor on context close

java.lang.IllegalStateException: LifecycleProcessor not initialized - call 'refresh' before invoking lifecycle methods via the context: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@797badd3: startup date [Thu Apr 13 10:20:35 BST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getLifecycleProcessor(AbstractApplicationContext.java:360) [spring-context-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1057) [spring-context-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1010) [spring-context-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleRunFailure(SpringApplication.java:794) [spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:325) [spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1162) [spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1151) [spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at fi.ma.vegshopping.app.VegShoppingApplication.main(VegShoppingApplication.java:16) [classes/:na]
```

Comment: For starters, you're somehow using an ancient version of Spring (3.2.6) with the latest Spring Boot. Stop overriding some-but-not-all versions.

Comment: Change all your scans from "fi.ma.vegshopping.impl" to "fi.ma.vegshopping"...